# Make custom Ubuntu flavour

Tags: live-usb, configuration, live-cd

I have seen some videos on how to make Ubuntu into a beautiful and efficient i3 system with all unnecessary apps removed. But rather than having to configuring such a system multiple times, I would prefer to make a flavour of Ubuntu myself. How difficult would it be to do that?

Comment: This is rather subjective question. It depends on your linux (Ubuntu) experience. A beginner might find it a bit difficult, an advanced user might find it easy. It depends on how deep you go with the (re)configuration. There are certain core apps (gedit, nautilus, apparmor, kernel, etc) that should not be removed, because removing them will break system functionality.